# What's the difference between FOREGROUND and TEXT_FOREGROUND in Synth?

Tags: java, swing, synth

What's the difference between FOREGROUND and TEXT_FOREGROUND in Synth? For example, `<Color value="red" type="FOREGROUND"/>` and `<Color value="red" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>`

Comment: question is about Synth Look and Feel or Nimbus base

Answer (score 0):

Typically, any text component, be it a `Label`, `Button`, `TextField` and whatnot will interpret `FOREGROUND` as 'text color'. Yes, that is definitely misleading.

`TEXT_FOREGROUND` is typically used as the 'selected component's text color', as in `ComboBox`. (`TEXT_BACKGROUND` is thus the 'selected component's background color')